# What's a neat way to avoid/manage these heap variables?

Tags: c++, qt, heap-memory

I'm developing a server app in QT in which i'm handling multiple clients. For every new incoming connection, i'm allocating three variables which actually keep track of incoming data i.e. `buffer`, `totalBytesToRead` and `numOfBytesRead`.

Here is the function in which i'm allocating it

```
void myNetworkClass::newConnection() {
    
    QTcpSocket *newSocket = server.nextPendingConnection();
    if(newSocket == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
    ++s_ConnectionsCount;
    
    // Allocate space on heap for these variables
    QByteArray *buffer = new QByteArray;
    size_t *totalBytesToRead = new size_t(0);
    size_t *numOfBytesRead = new size_t(0);

    QObject::connect(newSocket, &QAbstractSocket::disconnected, this, [=]() {this->onDisconnection(newSocket, buffer, totalBytesToRead, numOfBytesRead);} );
    QObject::connect(newSocket, &QIODevice::readyRead, this, [=]() {this->onRecvData(newSocket, buffer, totalBytesToRead, numOfBytesRead);} );
}
```

Whenever the clients disconnect or my server decides the client to be removed I've used the old fashion `delete` on these variables rather then `setParent()` because these are not `OObjects`.

Keeping track of `delete` and constantly allocating/deallocating `heap` space is bothering me. Is there a neat solution for this ?

P.S: `stack` is not a solution as i cannot guess the number of clients/connections.

Comment: This is what `std::shared_ptr` is for. No need to "keep track" of anything. `std::shared_ptr` will automatically delete everything for you.

Comment: Create a structure to hold the data together? Create a single instance of this structure, and use the pointer-to operator `&` to get the needed pointers to the members of the structure. Or use smart pointers (e.g. `std::unique_ptr`, preferably together with a structure).

Comment: Or refactor your code so that e.g. `onRecvData` doesn't need the pointer arguments, because when the function is called those arguments are unchanged from when you created them. For example, when `onRecvData` is called the variable `totalBytesToRead` is pointing to a `size_t` object whose value is `0`. Those variables are just don't needed at that point. All that's really needed is the socket.

Comment: At very first: Pack all data into a single struct or class. This eliminates deletion of all the data items individually. Instead of two separate lambdas you might connect class + member function to the signals, and on disconnecting the object might automatically disconnect itself – with the last thing doing deleting itself as well (that's fine as long as this is the very last action the object does).

Comment: On a different note I would refactor your whole class, so that you separate server handling (the code receiving new connections) and the connections themselves (the code that reads and writes to the connected sockets). That would make it much easier to get rid of all the pointers you currently have as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Would you kindly elaborate your statement a little more (?) Do you mean to say that i should create two classes i.e. one for receiving newConnections and other for read/write data from/to socket ?

Comment: "Do you mean to say that i should create two classes i.e. one for receiving newConnections and other for read/write data from socket?" Yes that's exactly what I mean. The "newConnections" handling class could have a list of the "connection" objects so it can delete them as needed. And use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` for the "connection" objects.

Comment: I think you should use `new` only when really necessary (rarely), and wrapped in a class (check RAII). You see a lot of `new`s in Qt examples because it's (was?) a convenient memory management choice for GUI frameworks (widgets life are managed by their parents), but that shouldn't influence your business logic.